# Popping and appending to always have a list of length of 4 elements

Tags: python

Suppose I have an ordered list with four elements `{element1, element2, element3, element4}`. The list has to be always of length 4. If `element5` appears, I have to delete `element1` and append `element5` at the end. I will then obtain `{element2, element3, element4, element5}`.

I tested out an idea

```
ls = []

for i in range(100):
    if len(ls) > 4:
       ls.pop(0)
    ls.append(i)
```

For me, it worked, but it is a lot of lines of code for not that much. Is there a more pythonic and elegant way to do that?

Comment: `ls = ls[len(ls)==4:4] + [i]`?

Comment: @Nick I wish to have an ordered list and something elegant

Comment: That will maintain ordering. In what way is it not "elegant"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using collections.deque:
https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html

Example:

```
>>> from collections import deque

>>> d = deque([4,3,2,13],4)      # initializing with max of 4 elements

>>> d
deque([4, 3, 2, 13], maxlen=4)

>>> d.append(-1)                 # appending will discard first element, if max size is exceeded 

>>> d
deque([3, 2, 13, -1], maxlen=4) 

>>> d[0]                         # accessing individual index
3   

>>> d[0:1]                       # not possible to access slices, though               
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#167>", line 1, in <module>
    d[0:1]
TypeError: sequence index must be integer, not 'slice'


>>> [c for c in d]               # generate a list from deque
[3, 2, 13, -1]

>>> list(d)                      # another approach to have a list from deque
[3, 2, 13, -1]

>>> sorted(d)                    # creates a sorted list (does not change original deque)
[-1, 2, 3, 13]

>>> d
deque([3, 2, 13, -1], maxlen=4)

>>> d = deque(sorted(d), 4)      # if you want to sort, recreate it using sorted()

>>> d
deque([-1, 2, 3, 13], maxlen=4)
```

Comment: Rather than just providing a link to a manual page (which may break in the future), please provide some sample code which answers the question.

Comment: It might be nice to use that, but can you make at least an example